# "at client-side" vs "on the client-side"

Tags: prepositions

I'm a little bit confuse with the use of client-side as a noun (In the context of Computer science, a client-server architecture). For instance , I used to say:

"I propose to install a tool at client-side"

But a friend of mine (that is not a native), told me that the right way is:
"I propose to install a tool on client-side"

That sounds weird to me, maybe adding "the" sounds better:
"I propose to install a tool on the client-side"

But the point is: what is the right way? (specially in formal writting).
Thanks in advance,

Comment: In what context? Do you mean client as opposed to server in client-server, or client as in customer?  If it's the former, then "install a tool on the client" works for me.

Comment: Without wishing to get bogged down in whether it's an adjectival or adverbial usage, I'll just point out that you don't actually *need* a preposition at all: [The customer uses a RIA Java application, with Java 8 installed client side.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Java+is+installed+client+side%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22Java+is+installed+client+side%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.8095j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22the+customer+uses+a+RIA+Java+application,+with+Java+8+installed+client+side%22)

Comment: In terms of what you heard--"client-side" or "client site"?

Comment: @JeffUK yes, in a computer science perspective :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "on" for hardware, "at" for location.

"Install the tool *on the client-side* computers"

vs

"Install the tool on the computers *at the client-side* office"

Note that I think to use "client-side" as a noun is short hand. It would be more specific to use terms such as "client-side computer", "client-side application" or "client-side network". In formal technical documentation it's better to be too specific than not specific enough. That said, the context usually provides clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The Software Engineering Institute at Carnegie-Mellon University CMU is a good source of best-practice terminology in computing science, including this [Glossary](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/architecture/start/glossary/) of Software Architecture terms.

If you search for "client-side" on the CMU site, you will find 60+ examples of professional usage, some with "on", others with "at", others with "the" and others without.

Based on the CMU examples: **I propose to install a tool on the client-side** would be an acceptable way to express your thought.

Alternatively, you could avoid the issue entirely by writing:
`I propose to install a tool client-side.` Which would also be correct.

Comment: I've added my own answer but this is a good one as well. I also agree that the last option in this post is likely the best. I would go a step further and modify it to: "I propose we install the tool client-side."

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some insight after 30 years in the computer science field.

Client side obviously means the "client computer" (meaning the end-users computer versus the server). Of course I expect you know this. I'm just stating it for those who may not be computer scientists or software engineer types.

**We would typically say (all of these are good options):**

1. I propose to install the tool client-side.
2. I propose to install on the client-side.
3. I propose to install it on the client-side.
4. I propose to do the installation client-side.
5. I propose to do the installation on the client-side.

Even simply...

1. I propose installation client-side.
2. I propose installation on the client-side.

You *CAN* use "at". There is nothing wrong with using: *"I propose we install a tool at the client-side."*. Grammatically it's probably even more correct. However, idiomatically and colloquially we tend not to say it in that form.

**If you wanted to use "at", it would be more idiomatic to say:**

1. "I propose we install at the client-side."
2. "I propose we install the tool(s) at the client-side."

versus

"I propose to install a tool at the client-side."

That last option will be a dead giveaway that you are non-native speaker and not used to English in a technology environment.